# Remove specific field if the column matches on the other column

Tags: awk, cut

I have a file contains duplicate fields.

**Sample file:**

```
ID     |Date|id     |date|name|...(up to 71 fields)
1313335|xxx |1313335|xx  |Zuan|
1677783|xxx |1677783|xx  |Zen|
11106A7|xxx |Zack   |
```

If the 1st column matches to the 3rd column then remove the 3rd and 4th column.

**Output:**

```
ID     |Date|name|...(up to 71 fields)
1313335|xxx |Zuan|
1677783|xxx |Zen |
11106A7|xxx |Zack|
```

I need your help guys!

Comment: Does your file always have 3 or 5 columns? Is the `ID` or `ID` always a single letter followed by a single space? Please don't answer this in a comment, [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the same amount of space in columns 1 and 3, you can use

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '$1==$3 { for(i = 3; i < NF-1; i++) $i = $(i+2); NF -= 2 } { print }' sample.txt
```

Explanation:

`-F '|' -v OFS='|'` set input and output field separators
`$1 == $3` condition: columns 1 and 3 are equal
`for(i = 3; i < NF-1; i++) $i = $(i+2);` starting from column 3 move the values 2 columns to the front
`NF -= 2` reduce the number of columns
`{ print }` unconditionally print the line

Note that the script doesn't remove columns 3 and 4 from the heading because `ID` is not equal to `id`.